# Cannot implicitly convert type 'unityengine.vector3' to 'float'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I have some code where the camera is follow and my error is:

> Assets/Scripts/CameraFollow.cs(15,46): error CS0029 : Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.Vector3' to float'
>
> Assets/Scripts/CameraFollow.cs(25,58): error CS0103 : The Name 'camWidth' does not exist in the current context

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    public Transform leftBounds;
    public Transform rightBounds;

    public float smoothDampTime = 0.15f;
    private  float smoothDampVelocity = Vector3.zero;

    private float camHeight, camWidht, levelMinX, levelMaxX;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
        camHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2;   
        camWidht = camHeight * Camera.main.aspect;

        float leftBoundsWidth = leftBounds.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer> ().bounds.size.x / 2;
        float rightBoundsWidth = rightBounds.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer> ().bounds.size.x / 2;

        levelMinX = leftBounds.position.x + leftBoundsWidth + (camWidth/2);
        levelMaxX = rightBounds.position.x - rightBoundsWidth - (camWidth/2);
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (target){

            float targetX = Mathf.Max (levelMinX, Mathf.Min (levelMaxX, target.position.x));

            float x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.x, targetX, ref smoothDampVelocity, smoothDampTime);
            
            transform.position = new Vector3(x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a type in `camWidht` != `camWidth` and yeah `float smoothDampVelocity = Vector3.zero;` doesn't make much sense ... Should probably simply be `0` (or nothing at all since that's the default value anyway)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation `Vector3.Zero` is Shorthand for writing `Vector3(0, 0, 0)`. and which is not of type `float`. You need to use the datatype accordingly like `transform.position`